# Check if user has specific Windows rights Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows 2003 server. I am try to create a PowerShell script that is checking to see if the user has the Windows rights (Right to debug a program, etc) or if he doesn't have that specific right, if he's in a group that has that right. If that succeeds, then it runs the System Configuration Checker that is included in the 2008 installer. I am having a hard time finding pertinent examples of doing this. Is this something that is possible within PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`whoami.exe /priv` can show this information, so would you be willing to parse its output? Maybe a function like this (which I'm sure I'm over complicating):

```
function Get-PrivilegeState {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string[]] $PrivilegeName = "*"
    )

    $WhoAmI = whoami.exe /priv

    foreach ($PrivilegeSearch in $PrivilegeName) {
        $RegEx = "^(?<privilege>{0})\s+.*?\s+(?<state>Enabled|Disabled)" -f ($PrivilegeSearch -replace '\*', '[A-z]*')
        $WhoAmI -match $RegEx | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_ -match $RegEx) {
                $FinalPrivilegeName = $Matches.privilege
                $State = $Matches.state

                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                    PrivilegeName = $FinalPrivilegeName
                    State = $State
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the user doesn't have the privilege, the function won't return anything. Here's how you could test for a specific privilege (this doesn't enable privileges; I'm assuming the application you need will do that automatically if the privilege has been granted):

```
if (Get-PrivilegeState SeRestorePrivilege) {
    # Privilege exists
    "Do something here"
}
else {
    Write-Error "Missing privilege"
}
```

And here are a few more examples of using the command:

```
# Get all granted privileges
Get-PrivilegeState

# Use wildcards:
Get-PrivilegeState *system*
```

Comment: whoami only returned a few lines for me, the state and 4 Privileges. I was hoping to get output like "Execute batch jobs" I feel like this is close though.

Comment: If you don't see the privilege, that should mean that it hasn't been granted to whoever is executing the command. If you're only getting four, it sounds like you're running from a regular prompt. Try to run it from an elevated prompt...